# PHP search field - Search String through files

Tags: php, search, search-engine

I am trying to search a directory (upload) for file names that match the search form.

I enter the word 'Bach' into the search field on my website. I would then like my script to search through all the files in the directory and display all of the files of which contain the word 'bach'.

This is the code that I have come up with, of which I expected it to work. I cannot see any visual errors and was wondering if you could help me.

At the moment, I am getting no results from the search.

```
if(isset($searchvalue))
{
    $dir = opendir('upload/'); 
    while ($read = readdir($dir)) 
    {
        if ($read!='.' && $read!='..') 
        { 
            if (stristr($searchvalue,$read))  //case insensitive
            {
                echo '<p><a href="upload/'.$read.'">'.$read.'</a></p>'; 
            }
        }
     }
     closedir($dir);  
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention what's wrong with it. Error? What's not happening that you want to happen?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. Basically, it is not matching the results. Meaning, there are no results when it tries to search the files.

Comment: There is also the [glob function](http://www.php.net/glob) that offers pattern matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($searchvalue)) {
    $dir = opendir('upload/');
    while ($read = readdir($dir)) {
        if ($read != '.' && $read != '..') {
            if (stristr($read, $searchvalue)) //case insensitive
            {
                echo '<p><a href="upload/' . $read . '">' . $read . '</a></p>';
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

Fix: Remove the quotes and turn the parameters in `stristr()` around. You were searching the filename in the search-input. But you have to search the search-input in the filename. Otherwise you check if "something.txt" is in "something" When you input "something" => evaluates to `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't quote the arguments in your stristr call.

Try this:

```
if (stristr($searchvalue,$read))
```

Comment: Tried removing the quotes, unfortunately it still does not work.